# Can a delegate variable be assigned to the calling object?

Tags: ios, uiview

Most of the time I am doing this:

```
self.someVC = [myVC alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
self.someVC.delegate = self;
```

Is there a way to set the delegate variable automatically?

```
-(void)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
         self.delegate = [the object that is calling initWithFrame];
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. You would have to inspect the call stack or something which I would not recommend. There are no standard facilities for this.

Even if it was possible, it would be a bad idea. You should use constructor or property injection as usual so the dependencies are clear and you don't confuse people that are reading your code.

Comment: I have been doing the "pass as parameter" trick, but was hoping for a work around, as this pattern occurs often.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom initializer that takes in the delegate object as a parameter.

Like this:

```
-(void)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame delegate:(id)delegate
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
         self.delegate = delegate;
..
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always provide a new initWithFrame method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect) aFrame delegate:(id)aDelegate {
    self = [super initWithFrame:aFrame];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = aDelegate;
    }
    return self;
}
```